# Passing dictionaries or objects in HTTP POST

Tags: android, python, http, dictionary, http-post

Is it a good practice to pass dictionaries as part of HTTP post payload.

Many python http client libraries support passing dictionaries as part of HTTP Payload. And server (python server in my limited experience) parses the request and returns a dictionary.

However, android client (okhttp) doesn't support passing dictionaries (or any objects for that matter). It only supports passing "key"->"value", where value is usually a string.

My question: Is it good practice to pass dictionaries, or should we encode (json, since it is popular) before passing any objects?

Comment: Pass it with `JSON`. I think it's easy. because `dictionary` is just like `JSONArray`

Comment: I think a json approach is better.

Comment: Use Json objects, you can use Json parsing libraries to directly parse Objects into Json string and send to server